# List only my posted question in Stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Hi,

How to only view/list my posted question in this Stackoverflow when I am in Stackoverflow HOME page. Previously, I used my name(Srinivasan) link to list only my posted questions.

Now it seems the functionality is somewhat changed. Please help me on this?

Comment: Wanna ask too. Is there any stackoverflow / stackexchange API ?

Comment: @user143844, there is, see [StackApps](http://stackapps.com).

Answer (score 1):

Click your name at the top of the page, and then click the profile link.

[image: profile link]

Comment: Hey, the middle click on my name (to open in a new tab) doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Greg: Of course not, they've changed it from a link to a popup menue. Can't say I like it, though. I used to middle-click, too!